# mySql Query running super slow

Tags: mysql

I have seen a few post's regarding slow queries but none had the answer I'm hoping for.

I've been staring at this query for ages and for some reason cant see whats making this so damn slow dates such as 2022-01-01 > 2022-12-21 even taking 80 seconds....

So here is the query

```
SELECT
    accounts.first_name,
    accounts.last_name,
    accounts.email,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(ID)
    FROM
        customer_migration_details
    WHERE
        date_opened BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' AND customer_migration_details.Assigned_to = accounts.email GROUP BY `accounts`.`email` LIMIT 1
) AS 'New Customers'
FROM
    customer_migration_details
RIGHT JOIN accounts ON customer_migration_details.Assigned_to = accounts.email
WHERE
    date_opened BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' AND customer_migration_details.Assigned_to = accounts.email AND accounts.role LIKE '%Sales%'
GROUP BY
    `accounts`.`email`
```

Heres the results

[image]

but here is the annoying part.

```
Showing rows 0 - 7 (8 total, Query took 109.5797 seconds.)
```

Theres got to be something im missing in the subquery maybe thats causing this to take so long.

Comment: How much is the size of the table and also do you index on those columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` ***or*** use a correlated sub-query, but not both at the same time.

```
SELECT
    accounts.first_name,
    accounts.last_name,
    accounts.email,
    COUNT(customer_migration_details.id)  AS new_customers
FROM
    accounts 
LEFT JOIN
    customer_migration_details
        ON  customer_migration_details.assigned_to = accounts.email
        AND customer_migration_details.date_opened BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
WHERE
    accounts.role LIKE '%Sales%'
GROUP BY
    accounts.email
```

Or...

```
SELECT
    accounts.first_name,
    accounts.last_name,
    accounts.email,
    (
      SELECT
          COUNT(ID)
      FROM
          customer_migration_details
      WHERE
              date_opened BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
          AND assigned_to = accounts.email
    )
      AS new_customers
FROM
    accounts
WHERE
    accounts.role LIKE '%Sales%'
```

***Notes:***

It's bad practice to put spaces, etc, in column names, so I changed `New Customers` to `new_customers`.

`LIKE '%Sales%'` can't use an index, so will scan each and every account row.

Comment: Not all heros wear capes, had a look through your adaptation of the query and its honestly just helped me with a few queries i have. Thank you so so much

Comment: Could i possibly pick you brains with another query?  this one has subqueries to pull different info for different dates?

Comment: @Drew raise a new question and I'll look at it after my next meeting

Comment: It wont let me rais another question.....

Comment: @Drew - Just go to the main Stackoverflow page and click "Ask Question"

Comment: Tried says my account can't ask questions..... Looks like im on a question ban....
"You can’t post new questions right now...."

Comment: @Drew I upvoted your question, check if that helped.  Otherwise, all I can recommend is reading the following link, and other help pages on the site: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: No luck, will give that document a read asap

Comment: Do check the results -- `JOIN` occurs _before_ `GROUP BY`.  That is the `COUNT` may be incorrectly inflated.

Comment: "can't post now"==perhaps the site was down for maintenance; try again.

Comment: Read the tutorial -- it is an easy way to get another 100 Reputation points, which will let you do more things.

Comment: @Drew - Oops, my comment (above) about the tutorial was meant for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
acc:  INDEX(email)
cmd:  INDEX(Assigned_to, date_opened)
```

Having `GROUP BY  acc.email` in the subquery seems *wrong*. And it may be unnecessary in the outer query.

Do not say `COUNT(x)` unless you need to avoid counting rows with `x IS NULL`.  Instead, say simply `COUNT(*)`.

If `date_opened` is a `DATETIME`, then you have excluded all but one second of New Years Eve.

`LIKE` with an initial wildcard is a performance problem.  Are there multiple "roles" with "Sales" in them?

My brain gets scrambled when I see `RIGHT JOIN`.  Can it be turned around to be a `LEFT JOIN`?  Anyway, it seems to be an `INNER JOIN`.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Agreed, the point stands that `>= '2022-01-01' AND < '2023-01-01'` is significantly more robust.